# React Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, styled-components

Using styled components to produce a template for posts on a fitness app project I am working working on. I am trying to navigate to another screen via a styled component button I have configured on the post but I am getting the error in the title above.

I'm passing navigation which is why I'm a bit confused as to why it's not working. Any suggestions are appreciated. Code is below.

```
const Postcard = ({item}) => {

  const cardType = ({navigation}) => {
    if (item.food) {
      return(
      <Card>
          <PostInfo>
            <PostTypeImage source={{uri: item.postImage}} />
            <PostInfoText>
            <PostName>{item.id}</PostName>
            <PostTime>{item.foodTiming}</PostTime>
            <Edit onPress={() => {navigation.push('AddFood')}}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name='file-edit' size={20} color={'#1abc9c'}/>
            </Edit>
            </PostInfoText>
          </PostInfo>
          <PostText style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.food}</PostText>
          <PostText>This meal contained:</PostText>
          <PostText>Carbohydrates: {item.carbs} grams</PostText>
          <PostText>Protein: {item.protein} grams</PostText>
          <PostText>Fat: {item.fat} grams</PostText>
      </Card> 
      )
    } else {
      return (
      <Card>
          <PostInfo>
            <PostTypeImage source={{uri: item.postImage}} />
            <PostInfoText>
            <PostName>{item.id}</PostName>
            <Edit onPress={() => {navigation.push('AddWater')}}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name='file-edit' size={20} color={'#34e1eb'}/>
            </Edit>
            </PostInfoText>
          </PostInfo>
          <PostTextWater>{item.water} ml of water logged</PostTextWater>
      </Card>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
      cardType({item})
  )
}
```

Comment: Because `cardType` does not have access to navigation you only have one param item

Comment: Hi, I don't understand? Am I not passing cardType navigation?

Comment: In the `return cardType({item})` you are not passing navigation to destructure it.

Comment: I tried this and it has not resolved my issue :(

Comment: I have since resolved, thank you!